# How to get a string from another class?

Tags: java, string, class

Searched everywhere trying to find how to do this.
I want to get a string from one class that i set the variable before going into the second class and allow me to use it as a string in this class.

Basically there's a String called LastName that i want to use in another class.

Here's my code if needed.

First Login Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {
public void LoginScreen() {

    Agent AgentObject = new Agent();
    Citizen CitizenObject = new Citizen();

    String FirstName;
    String LastName;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    System.out.print("Please Enter Last Name: ");
    LastName = input.next();
    System.out.print("Please Enter First Name: ");
    FirstName = input.next();
    System.out.println("Hello " + FirstName + " " + LastName);

    System.out.print("Enter Password: ");
    String userinput = input.next();
    if (userinput.equals("Timmo")) {
        AgentObject.WelcomeAgent();
    } else {
        CitizenObject.WelcomeCitizen();
    }

}
}
```

Second Agent Class:

```
public class Agent {
public void WelcomeAgent() {
    Welcome WelcomeObject = new Welcome();
    Login LoginObject = new Login();

    System.out.println("Access Granted");
    System.out.print("Loading Data  ");
    int progress = 0;
    while (progress <= 100) {
        System.out.print(progress + " ");
        progress++;
    }
    System.out.println("    Data Loaded");

    System.out.println("Welcome Agent " + LastName);
    LoginObject.LoginScreen();
}
}
```

Any help is incredibly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Never name variables of fields of methods with starting uppercase symbol. It is bad style.

Comment: Doesnt Java block dead code? your `WelcomeAgent` shouldnt compile..

Comment: You are returning a string in a method that returns no data. LastName is not a local or field variable.. in Agent class... Make LastName a field so you can reuse it. Also assuming WelcomeAgent does compile, subsequent instructions wouldn't execute after the return  statement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see you are probably quite new to Java - so you may be lacking a few fundamentals.

Probably best to just pass the string in as a parameter to the method in your case
e.g.

```
public void WelcomeAgent(String lastName) {
```

and when you call the method, send that value in
e.g.

```
AgentObject.WelcomeAgent(userinput);
```

Btw, a few convention tips.  Variables and functions should start with a lower case . e.g.

```
String lastName;
```

and

```
Citizen citizen = new Citizen();
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem sorted :) Yeah i haven't used it for a while ill make sure to start with lowercase from now on

Comment: no worries, another tip - I'd "compress": int progress = 0;
    while (progress <= 100) {
        System.out.print(progress + " ");
        progress++;
    } into a for loop rather than use a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to access the value of LastName in class Agent ?

What if you change it like this

```
public class Login {

 String FirstName, LastName;



public void LoginScreen() {

Agent AgentObject = new Agent();
Citizen CitizenObject = new Citizen();
....
LastName = input.next();
 ...
 }

 public String getLastName()
 { return LastName; }
```

and in class Agent

you can use LoginObject.getLastName() to get the it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `getter` method for the `lastName` in your `Login` class. After setting the value in the `Login` class send the reference of this class object to the other classes where you want to use. Finally call the `onject.getLastName()` method and use it.

**Example:**

Suppose `Login` class and `Agent` class and `lastName` was declared in Login class then pass the reference of the Login class to the Agent class and access it from the Agent class using the `getter` method as I have stated above.